# The named parameter ' ' isnt defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting errors in my flutter app after an upgrade to flutter 3.3.6. The named parameters which throws errors as 'aren't defined' : elevation, color, shape

The snippet where i get the errors is listed below :

```
return ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: 110,
  child: RaisedButton(
      elevation: 0,
      child: isLoading
          ? _buildLoadingIndicatorWithColor(textColor)
          : Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: textColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16),
            ),
      color: communityColor,
      onPressed: onPressed,
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius))),
);
```

}

Here is another snippet where a similar error appears and the textColor parameter throws the same error :

```
return ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: minWidth,
  height: height,
  child: FlatButton(
    textColor: Colors.black87,
    child: this.child,
    onPressed: this.onPressed,
  ),
);
```

Here is the one related to materialTapTargetSize:

```
hasText
                ? TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        materialTapTargetSize:
                            MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap),
                    onPressed: _cancelSearch,
                    child: OBText(localizationService.user_search__cancel),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(
                    width: 15.0,
                  )
```

As per the following documentation I read https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons, there are changes that are needed to make it work. Help appreciated as I'm very new to flutter and a beginner to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RaisedButton is deprecated. You can use ElevatedButton(). Please check below code.

```
ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 110,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: communityColor,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        ),
        child: isLoading
            ? _buildLoadingIndicatorWithColor(textColor)
            : Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(color: textColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
              ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      ),
    );
```

For FlatButton()

```
ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: minWidth,
      height: height,
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: Colors.black87,
          tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        ),
        child: this.child,
        onPressed: this.onPressed,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Hello KK ! , a similar issue. the named parameter textColor isn't defined. I have updated the question !

Comment: Does ButtomTheme also need to be refactored to the following as per this article ? - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yohSuYrvyya5V1hB6j9pJskavCdVq9sVeTqSoEPsWH0/edit#

Comment: Answer updated check now

Comment: Hi. I forgot to add a small snippet below it. Have updated the question. Its related to materialTapTargetSize. I tired follwoing your approach but the same error appears.

Comment: Updated. materialTapTargetSize changed to tapTargetSize

Comment: Hi. I have updated the code in question nd separated the block so as to emphasize that they are different codes. Kindly check out.

Comment: The error is anyways solved despite the recent code being not part of Flat button.

Comment: **materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap**  to   **tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap**

Answer (score 1):

As ***K K Muhammed Fazil*** said change the `RaisedButton` to `ElevatedButton`

If that didn't work with you Try execute those below commands in the terminal:

First do This command

```
 flutter clean
```

And then this

```
 flutter pub get
```

Comment: Thanks. But the above worked.

Comment: oh ok, happy to here that

Comment: Sure. This is also one of the solutions as I've read in other posts. For anyone who reads this post.